# How to replace my Unix( SUSE Linux 10.1) raid drive

Tags: linux, raid1, opensuse

Im new to this server stuff and , i have a server with SUSE Linux 10.1 on it with Raid 1 hard drives , i want to replace one of the raid drives but don't really know if  i remove the drive and attach a new one will it automatically build the new drive , how can i know about this , and how to proceed with this process , any help, links to tutorials will be greatly appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Is your server using software RAID (mdadm) or a hardware RAID card?

Comment: its using a software RAID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using mdadm?

You need to replace it (you need to 'fail' it first to do that), and remove it, and then add a new drive to the remaining part of the array. It will rebuild it itself.

[Link](http://www.ducea.com/2009/03/08/mdadm-cheat-sheet/) <- see steps 3 and 4, and 5 to see if it's rebuilding and when it's done

If you're using anything else (hardware raid controller (card)), consult the proper documentation for that.